# Fixed point of interior of closed disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $D = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$. Let $A \subset \mathrm{int}D$. Let $A$ be connected and compact and let $D \setminus A$ be connected. Let $f:A \longrightarrow A$ be a continuous function and let $g:D \longrightarrow D$ be also continuous function such that $g_{|A} = f$.$\\$
Does it imply that there exists $x \in \mathrm{int}D$ such that $g(x)=x$?

Comment: Would you make an effort to improve the formulation of your question?

Comment: Is $D$ defined correctly? If $g$ is a function on $D$ then I don't see what you mean by $g|_A$, since $A \not \subset D$.

Comment: $A \subset \mathrm{int}D$. So must be $A \subset D$

Comment: Yes, but you defined $g$ to be a function on the circle $D$, but $A$ is not contained in that circle, so restricting $g$ to $A$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: oh you're right. I mean $D = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2  ≤1 \}$

Comment: Also you might want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: I've checked this. But I cant see how to prove this

Comment: Also please stop reposting your questions!

Comment: Do. Not. Repost. That rule is strictly upheld, because it will make the site less organized, and also likely leads to waste of effort, when somebody spends time to reproduce an answer you already got elsewhere. Veterans think it is rude to waste their time in this manner, and will react accordingly.

Comment: I promise I never repost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brouwer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) states, that $g$ already has a fixed point in the convex closure of $A$ (or the smallest closed ball containing $A$). Since $A$ lies in the interior of $D$, also the convex closure lays in the interior (or you deform $A$ continuously into something convex and don't need the convex closure), hence the fix point lays in the interior of $D$.

Comment: I'm wondering about this fixed point @ctst. You said that the existance of the fixed point in the interior of $D$ resulted from Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem and the fixed point must lay in the convex closure of $A$. So let $B$ be the convex closure of $A$. Brouwer states that continuous function $g:B\longrightarrow B$ has a fixed point. But my function was defined $g:D\longrightarrow D$ , it's possible that $g(B)⊈B$, so the function $g:B\longrightarrow B$  doesn't exist. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Marendad Ah, yes you are right. Instead of the convex closure you need to deform $A$ topologically into something convex (you can do this, since it is simply connected/ $D\setminus A$ is connected and open). If you are not sure about it, you might want to take a closer look at this specific paragraph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#Convexity

Comment: What if $A = \{ (x,0): x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}] \} \cup \{ (0,y): y\in [0,\frac{1}{2}] \} \cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y = x,~ x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\}$. Can I deform it topologically into something convex ?